# How to read csv file into dataframe using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, opencsv

I just got a csv file that I want to load the dataset as dataframe using pandas.  However, I'm kinda confused this data format.

Here is the sample of data for two lines:

```
Name=John, Gender=M, BloodType=A, Location=New York, Age=18
Name=Mary, Gender=F, BloodType=AB, Location=Seatle, Age=30
```

How do I load this dataset into dataframe with columns (Name, Gender, BloodType,...etc)?

I will appreciate that someone gives me tips to start with!

Comment: Use [.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Yup, I do use pandas.read_csv(). Yet, it will make every column with this format 'attribute=value'.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `header=None` first:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Name=John,Gender=M,BloodType=A,Location=New York,Age=18
Name=Mary,Gender=F,BloodType=AB,Location=Seatle,Age=30"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=None)
print (df)
           0         1             2                  3       4
0  Name=John  Gender=M   BloodType=A  Location=New York  Age=18
1  Name=Mary  Gender=F  BloodType=AB    Location=Seatle  Age=30
```

Then [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select second lists, last change columns names:

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('=').str[1])
df1.columns = df.iloc[0].str.split('=').str[0].rename(None)
#if necessary
df1['Age'] = df1['Age'].astype(int)
print (df1)
   Name Gender BloodType  Location  Age
0  John      M         A  New York   18
1  Mary      F        AB    Seatle   30
```

Comment: I used the same way!

Answer (score 5):

Use the pandas read_csv method to read the csv file.
Here is a sample program how you can do that:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("path_to_csv_file")

print(data)
```